# Better Way to refresh ListView?

Tags: android, multithreading, listview

I have a Activty containing a custom ListView filled by Baseadapter.The Data displayed by this ListView changes all the time, so I need to refresh the List.

I do this by periodially calling notifyDataSetChanged() on my ListViewAdapter in a Thread and setting thread_paused to true if the activity is paused. Ugly as hell.

```
public void StartListener(){
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          while(!thread_paused){
              try {
                 Thread.sleep(5000);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                    ListViewA.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.v("refresh", "refreshed view");
             }
        });
      }
     } 
  }).start();
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
  super.onPause();
  thread_paused=true;
}
```

I know there has to be a a better way to do this, maybe some kind of listener on the datasource ?

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer: Just update the list when the data of the list changed. Updating the list without that changed data makes no sense, so what ever changes the data should call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Ok, so the the data is changed by a Service. Maybe binding the Activity to the Service and passing a custom Listener will do the trick ?

Answer (score 0):

solved it using a  [broadcastreceiver](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/WeatherPlus/src/com/commonsware/android/service)